# Misleading Java XML validation

Tags: java, xml, validation, xsd, xml-validation

I am validating XML against a XSD. But my java validation error message is different from XMLSpy's validation error message. Here XMLSpy is correct and java validation message is misleading. I am using following code to validate the XML:

```
SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setValidating(true);
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
saxParser.setProperty(JAXP_SCHEMA_LANGUAGE, W3C_XML_SCHEMA);

saxParser.setProperty(JAXP_SCHEMA_SOURCE,new File("TXLife2.26.00.xsd"));
MySAXHandler dh = new MySAXHandler();
saxParser.parse(new File("test.xml"), dh);
```

Java validation message says:

> cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element '<element>'.

But XMLSpy says:

> Element <element> is not allowed at this location under element <parent_element>

Comment: The content of the error messages id dependent upon the parser implementation being used.

Comment: What is your question? If the answer to that is "How do I fix this?", the answer is you're kind of SOL

Comment: @Pangea Is there anyway to resolve it?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav Not sure if XmlSpy lets you choose the parser implementation. If it does then change it to use the same implementation as the JDK.

Comment: @Pangea XMLSpy is not my problem. If I submit original xml to external system it throws error but when I reorder the xml as per XMLSpy suggestions then it works fine.

Comment: @HimanshuYadav I doubt that. Share your xsd and xml

Comment: @Pangea XSD is more than 20000 lines. Is there a way to mail you or attach the file here?

Comment: @HimanshuYadav - then reduce the xsd to include only the stuff that is causing the issue...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9915/discussion-between-himanshu-yadav-and-pangea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you get depends on the validator you are using. Both are reporting the same error. If you want a Java XSD validator with better error messages, give Saxon a try: you may prefer it. But error reporting is an imprecise art: in designing error messages, an implementor is working with limited information about (a) what the user intended, and (b) how much the user understands about the technology.

Comment: Saxon EE has the functionality to validate XML against a XSD. Is there any freeware library which does the same thing?